# How to do a simple math with TIME in CASE inside CREATEVIEW

Tags: mysql

If the checkout time more than 17:00:00, then i want to calculate the overtime, for example, if we checkout at 19:00:00 then the math is 19:00:00 - 17:00:00 = 02:00:00. how i can do it?

the code below resulting an error:

```
CREATE VIEW absenstatus AS SELECT pin, name, date,
CASE WHEN checkout > '17:00:00' THEN checkout - 17:00:00 END as overtime
FROM absenfinal
GROUP BY tanggal, pin
```

Comment: The '-' is numeric operator. For time , I think you need to use functions

Comment: Letting people guess what errors you are getting is not the smart thing to do (please go read [ask]) - but `checkout - 17:00:00` is of course invalid syntax. 17 colon 00 colon 00 is not an expression that makes sense.

Comment: use subtime function and the same applies for > too

Comment: Run a simple query first before you create it as view..

Comment: What value should `overtime` take when checkout is not later than `17:00:00`? Also, as others have indicated, "an error" isn't an actual problem description.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is the error ?

Try this if checkout is not a string : (Obviously you can not use simple soustraction for dates)

```
CREATE VIEW absenstatus AS SELECT pin, name, date,
CASE WHEN checkout > 17:00:00 THEN SUBTIME(checkout , 17:00:00) END as overtime
FROM absenfinal
GROUP BY tanggal, pin
```

**Examples :**

```
SELECT SUBDATE('2011-05-21 12:15:56', INTERVAL '3 02:10:32' DAY_SECOND) AS SUBDATE1, 
       SUBDATE('2011-05-21', 12) AS SUBDATE2,
       DATE_SUB('2011-05-21', INTERVAL 3 MONTH) AS DATE_SUB;

SELECT SUBTIME('2011-05-21 12:15:56', '18:35:15') AS SUBTIME1,
       SUBTIME('12:15:56', '8:35:15') AS SUBTIME2;
```

**Gives you :**

```
SUBDATE1            | SUBDATE2   | DATE_SUB
2011-05-18 10:05:24 | 2011-05-09 | 2011-02-21

SUBTIME1            | SUBTIME2
2011-05-20 17:40:41 | 03:40:41
```